# Gradient of convex functions

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization, convex-geometry

Let $f$ be a convex and differentiable function in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Then if we have a minimizing sequence $\{x_k\}$ (i.e. $f(x_{k+1})\le f(x_k)$), and if we also know that
$$\liminf_{k\to\infty}\|\nabla f(x_k)\|=0,$$
will we get
$$\lim_{k\to\infty}\|\nabla f(x_k)\|=0~?$$
If not, will it be true if we add L-smoothness or strong convexity?